# Action on Google - Alpha not working

Tags: actions-on-google

My test version is working fine but when I release to alpha the same functionality that worked in test version is not working in alpha.

Issues,

1. User whose language is English (UK) when try to invoke my action works fine in test version but does not work in alpha. It simple says "Name of action" isn't responding now while in English(United States) alpha does respond correctly. I have not added any locales for English rather I have gone for English as a language option.
2. Intents that are working in test version but are not working in alpha version, funny thing is that my fulfilment cloud function does not even get called on alpha for the same input that I have tested with test version.

This is frustrating. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Has this user opted in to the alpha release through their phone in the Google Assistant directory?

Comment: yes, the issue is random. I have been using since 3 days no issue now.